# Unable to return email message body

Tags: python-3.x, email, imaplib

I have created a class to read emails and convert to a dataframe. This works for all HEADER data but I am unable to parse the message content and have tried numerous methods. I am following a tutorial from here http://beneathdata.com/how-to/email-behavior-analysis/

I have tried amending the def fetch_and_parse function in the code to select the message content but nothing seems to return. I have also tried amending the FETCH query but I'm lost.

```
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
import email as em
from email.utils import parsedate, parsedate_tz
from email.parser import HeaderParser


class OutlookAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, folder=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.folder = folder

    def login(self):
        self.conn = IMAP4_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
        response = self.conn.login(self.username, self.password)
        return response

    def search(self, query, folder=None, readonly=False):
        ff = self.folder if self.folder else folder
        self.conn.select(ff, readonly)
        resp, data = self.conn.search(None, query)
        return data

    def fetch(self, uids, query):
        uid_arr = b','.join(uids[0].split())
        resp, data = self.conn.fetch(uid_arr, query)
        return data

    def fetch_and_parse(self, uids, query):
        data = self.fetch(uids, query)
        parser = HeaderParser()
        emails = []

        for email in data:
            if len(email) < 2:
                continue
            msg = em.message_from_bytes(email[1]).as_string()

            emails.append(parser.parsestr(msg))

        return emails

    def load_parse_query(self, search_query, fetch_query, folder=None, readonly=False):
        '''Perform search and fetch on an imap Gmail account. After fetching relevant info
        from fetch query, parse into a dict-like email object, return list of emails.'''
        uids = self.search(search_query, folder, readonly)
        return self.fetch_and_parse(uids, fetch_query)




import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import getpass
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import matplotlib.dates as dates
#import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, date

imap_password = getpass.getpass()

outlook = OutlookAccount(username='some@email.com', password=imap_password)
outlook.login()

daysback = 6000 # ~10yrs...make this whatever ya like
notsince = 0 # since now.
since = (date.today() - timedelta(daysback)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
before = (date.today() - timedelta(notsince)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

SEARCH = '(SENTSINCE {si} SENTBEFORE {bf})'.format(si=since, bf=before)
ALL_HEADERS = '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])'

# Search and fetch emails!
received = outlook.load_parse_query(search_query=SEARCH, 
                                  fetch_query=ALL_HEADERS, 
                                  folder='"INBOX"')


#create function to convert to dataframe

def scrub_email(headers):   
    # IMAP sometimes returns fields with varying capitalization. Lowercase each header name.
    return dict([(title.lower(), value) for title, value in headers]) 

df = pd.dataframe([scrub_email(email._headers) for email in received])
```

I want the dataframe to include all headers data and a field that includes the email message content/body.

Answer (score 0):

Body needed to be selected as part of fetc_and_parse fusing something like:

```
if mime_msg.is_multipart():
        for part in mime_msg.walk():
            if part.is_multipart():
                for subpart in part.get_payload():
                    if subpart.is_multipart():
                        for subsubpart in subpart.get_payload():
                            body = body + str(subsubpart.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
                    else:
                        body = body + str(subpart.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
            else:
                body = body + str(part.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'
else:
    body = body + str(mime_msg.get_payload(decode=True)) + '\n'

body = bytes(body,'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```